# What is the difference between "electric" and "electrical" and their usage?

Tags: differences, adjectives, suffixes, ic-ical

What is the difference between **electric** and **electrical** and their usage?

For example, what is the difference between "electrical machine" and "electric machine"?

Comment: Related: ["Electronic" vs. "electric"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5699/electronic-vs-electric) and some general discussion at [Why is it *geometric_* but *theoretic_al_*?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/why-is-it-geometric-but-theoretic-al) with two awesome answers.

Comment: In Physics I've only encountered "electric" (electric field, electric charge, electric dipole, etc.). These are not directly related to electricity.

Comment: I found this related link [Difference between ‘electronic’, ‘electric’, and ‘electrical’](https://jakubmarian.com/difference-between-electronic-electric-and-electrical/).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

These two words have a large semantic overlap, but at the edges there are a few key differences.

- *Electric* is used to describe things pertaining to electricity.  It can also be used metaphorically: "the evening was electric".
- *Electrical* can be used nearly everywhere that *electric* is used when pertaining to electricity (aside from some set phrases). It is *not* generally used metaphorically in the way *electric* is.  The word *electrical* can also be used in an additional domain: things *concerning* electricity.  So, generally, people do not say "electric engineer" unless the engineer runs on electricity; instead they say "electrical engineer".

So, in the case of "electric(al) machine" from your question, since you are talking about something that runs on electricity, the two words are essentially identical in meaning.

Comment: are you suggesting that I've been wasting my time trying to learn the [Electrical Slide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vAwpTva9ERk)?  ;-)

Comment: As a non-native English speaker, the differentiation between "pertaining to" vs. "concerning" doesn't make things clearer. Could you paraphrase your usage of those terms here to help me understand?

Answer (score 16):

Here's a simple distinguishment which I hope will help:

> Electric refers to anything that runs on electricity, i.e. “electric kettle”
>
> Electrical refers to something related to electricity, i.e. “electrical faults”, “electrical component”.

"Electric" is used in front of a device or machine that runs on electricity. It is used when the object has been specified.

"Electrical" is used in a more general sense, as in referring to ambiguous nouns. (By ambiguous, I mean unspecified, e.g. machine, appliance). "electrical" is also used when the object is specified, but the object is not run on electricity, but is related to electricity, i.e. Electrical engineer.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_machine

So why this can't be called and didn't got referred to as "electric machine" ?

Comment: Hmmm.... interesting. I'll try to clarify matters.

Comment: The problem is that the dichotomy you have listed here is not actually how the words are used.  *Electrical* can also be used to refer to *electric* things: [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/electrical).

Comment: @Computist - That Wikipedia article switches between "electric" and "electrical" without any consistency at all.  Don't use it as a style guide.

Comment: @MT_Head: I don't think you are right that Wikipedia switches between "electric" and "electrical" without *any* consistency.  I think you probably assumed that without great investigation. And I was also *not* using it as a style guide. It was just one of the references out there for use.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_machine
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_machine

both exist. I also searched oed.com and it only has "electric machine".

Comment: @Computist - Here's a sample of what I meant: "**Generator** (Main article: Electrical generator) An electric generator is a device that converts mechanical energy to electrical energy. "  Within the space of five words, they manage to call it both an "electric" and an "electrical" generator.  Perhaps you have another name for it, but I call that inconsistency.  I didn't mean to suggest that you *were* using it as a style guide, BTW, just that - if you were planning to - it might not be the best idea.

Comment: @Computist - And, amusingly, that link to "Electrical generator" actually goes to an article titled "Electric generator."

Answer (score 2):

*Electric* means "of, worked by, charged with, or producing electricity."
It can be used figuratively, as in "the atmosphere was electric;" to refer to a musical instrument, as in *electric guitar*; or to refer to a color, as in *electric blue*.

*Electrical* means:

- operating by or producing electricity
- concerned with electricity

*Electric* cannot be always replaced with *electrical*; you don't say *electrical guitar*, or "the atmosphere was electrical" (if not to mean something else than the phrase using *electric*).

Comment: Since you mentioned musical instruments, note that  electric pianos, electronic pianos, and digital pianos are three different things, though of course they all use electricity.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what has been said so far, "electric," unlike "electrical," can be used as a noun for an electrically powered machine or vehicle.

E.g.

> [The lawmower is an electric](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/electrical).

Answer (score 0):

Electric used about something that works using electricity, for example, electric cooker , electric guitar, electric kettle.
Electrical used about things in general that use electricity, or people whose job is to make or repair these things: a company manufacturing electrical goods|, an electrical engineer
electronic used about equipment such as computers and televisions that work by using extremely small electrical parts, or about systems that work using computers: Most kids love electronic games.|Email is the short word for electronic mail.