# Is "analeptical" correct? Form of "analepses"

Tags: word-choice, dictionaries, diction

My teacher was editing my essay and change `analepses` (plural of `analepsis`) to `analeptical`. I'm trying to use the definition of a flashback.

Here is the context:

Original sentence:

> Analepses in the characters is inspired through the cellist's music.

Edited sentence:

> The cellist's music inspires analeptical moments for the characters.

What I think I should finally use:

> The cellist's music inspires analepses for the characters.

Is the edited sentence more correct, or the final one I think I should use?

Comment: Phew! That was an interesting thing to dig into! But I kinda doubt this question is going to attract a storm of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note - Dispensador's link isn't to OED, it's to Oxford Dictionaries online (someone else can explain how that relates to OED, which I'm afraid still requires a subscription to access).

Anyway, I did *my* Lit Crit studies 40 years ago, so I didn't *quite* get exposed to this relatively recent usage at the time. But here are the relevant bits from the "real" OED...

> **analeptic, adj. and n.**
>    Sense 2: *Literary Criticism. Of the nature of an **analepsis** or **flashback***.
>
> **analepsis, n.**
>    Sense 4: *Literary Criticism. The narration of an event at a point later than its chronological place in a story; an instance of this, a **flashback**. Cf. [**prolepsis**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prolepsis)*.

You can look up (non-medical! :) *prolepsis* there - it's all just more about with narrative, syntax, and other Lit Crit stuff.

---

Armed with the information above, it should be reasonably clear that OP's original use of the *noun* form was at the very least "inelegant" (replacing *analepsis* by *flashback* produces nonsense).

Sadly for OP's teacher, I must report that OED doesn't list this figurative Lit Crit usage under the more explicitly adjectival form *analeptical*. As indicated above, it's new to me. But here's my take...

We're looking at something like the [*electric/electrical*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31649/) distinction. OED says both ***analeptic*** and ***analeptical*** are valid adjectives, but the second is *only* used in the literal medical sense. Therefore the stylistically and grammatically preferred rephrasing should be (drumroll! :) ...

> *The cellist's music inspires **analeptic** moments for the characters.*

---

TL;DR: The teacher is more right than OP. ***Analepsis*** is a noun like *allegory, imagery, paradox*. It's a characteristic of (or device used within) a narrative, not something that can be "inspired" in the *characters* within the narrative.
But the dictionary makes it clear ***analeptic*** (not ***analeptical***) is the correct Lit Crit adjective.

Comment: Thank you, especially for informing me of the non-medical definition of analeptic. That's what I was hoping for. Anyways, I'm down to two possible sentences. Do you mind letting me know which one is better? 1. `The cellist’s music elicits prophetic moments and feelings of analepsis in the characters` and 2. `The cellist’s music elicits analeptic and prophetic moments in the characters`

Comment: @mike: Hey! That's your teacher's job, not mine! :) Seriously, we're really just talking about personal stylistic choices here. But I personally would avoid the pointless "overload" of dragging both *moments* and *feelings* into a context where all you actually care about is the contrast between *forward-* and *backward-looking* perspectives. Per my answer, I don't really understand how you want to apply ***analepXXX*** to *the experiences of fictional characters within a work*, but if you're sure that's what you mean, surely the obvious "opposite" term must be ***prolepsis***.