# How do we use the words 'electric' and 'electrical' correctly?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

These two words are used differently as shown below:
Electric engineering (incorrect✖)
Electrical engineering (correct✓)
Electrical lamp (incorrect✖)
Electric lamp (correct✓)
And sometimes, they're used interchangeably as shown below:
Electric appliance (correct✓)
Electrical appliance (correct✓)
I am curious to know how these words are used correctly, how to know which one to use, for instance, with 'substation'.

Comment: Hi Gurpreet. Please search in the site using keywords to see if the question has already been asked.

Comment: Looks like duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/q/31649/623