# Electric car or electrical car

Tags: ic-ical

I know the right answer is the former one thanks to Google, but is there a reason behind it other than idiomatic usage?

Comment: [Link](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31649/what-is-the-difference-between-electric-and-electrical-and-their-usage) It's quite easy to tell between them. It is not idiomatic, and there is a rule.